# Why doesnt a wet circuit work

Tags: electric-circuits, water, home-experiment, short-circuits

I mistakenly poured water on my the area of my TV remote which has the cell and apparently the circuit connections.A thing to ponder is that why doesnt a circuit work when it becomes wet , despite it being a good conductor. I see this in case of modems , telephones

---

I searched on net and it said that water provides an extra path leading to short circuit which I dont find justifiable like how is there a short circuit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if there is a wire coming from the positive terminal of the battery, then into the remote’s circuitry then to the negative terminal, water may cause a link between these wires before the current has a chance to circulate through this circuitry. This will obviously stop the remote from working at all.

Sometimes the water will short other component wires “further down-stream” inside the circuit board and the remote may partially work.

Of course such electronic circuits are much more complicated and these are simple examples of what may be a more complicated process.